# How to make accordion close when other is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with some elementor accordion...

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.elementor-tab-title').click(function () {
        let active = document.querySelectorAll(".elementor-tab-title elementor-active");
        for(let j = 0; j < active.length; j++){
         active[j].classList.remove("elementor-active");
         active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null; //or 0px
        }
    });
}
);
```

So, area-selected and area-expanded is switching to false when is closed and to true when its opened.

Class is switching from 'elementor-tab-title' when closed to 'elementor-tab-title elementor-active' when opened.

There are 6 of them, and I just can't figure out how to make them close when another is clicked to open.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop yourself using vanilla, you could use jQuery to do that for you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.elementor-tab-title').click(function () {
        jQuery('.elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('elementor-active');
    });
});
```

Basically you're saying : remove all active classes regardless which one has it for all the tab-titles and add the active class to the clicked item (which is "this")

Answer (score -1):

Using this script you can Set Elementor Accordion Closed by Default!

[Here](https://googlewebstoryus.com/keep-accordion-closed-by-default#step1) is script and step that really work for me I did use this on my site.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35714424)